# neovim insert mode, inject predefined text (Elixir pipe operator)

Tags: neovim

I would like to replicate RStudio's "insert pipe operator" hotkey in insert mode.
When hitting `<C-M>`, I would like the following symbols to be typed: `|>`.

Is this possible?

I have tried the following:

```
# Keybind function
local function map(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
  local options = {noremap = true}
  if opts then options = vim.tbl_extend('force', options, opts) end
  vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, lhs, rhs, options)
end

# Not working
map('i', '<C-M>', '|>')
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with my example was that `<C-m>` is already in use by neovim.

The following works:

```
local function map(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
  local options = {noremap = true}
  if opts then options = vim.tbl_extend('force', options, opts) end
  vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, lhs, rhs, options)
end

map('i', '<C-e>', '|>')
```